# General question about deploying a react App

Tags: reactjs, firebase, deployment, build, axios

As a beginner in React, I'm currently developing an e-commerce mock-up locally on my computer.

I have the central App, all the React environnment, my pages, my components, the helpers functions, my pictures in an `src/asset/images` folder, etc, etc.

The data (products ID, description, prices, etc) come from a `Firebase` source which are requested by `Axios`.

Everything works great, as if it's quite frustrating, since no one can see the project except me.

Hence my questions:

- how to deploy the website on the real Internet, for the project to be visible ?
- will all the dynamically charged content (especially pictures) follow and still be accessible ?
- is it better to load the images using the `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` ?

Thank you for your advices,

Have a great day everyone

Answer (score 0):

to deploy. you have many options , as you are already using firebase.fireabse provide hosting too. (free)
check out this link
https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/quickstart